# Find files alphabetically before a given string

Tags: bash, filter

If I have a directory full of files and sub directories. What is the best way to list just the regular files which fall alphabetically before a given string?

Currently the best I can do using bash is the following:

```
for x in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort`
do
   if [[ "$x" > './reference' ]]
   then
      break
   fi

   echo $x
done
```

I feel like there is a more concise way to do this, but I'm not sure what it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need all of them

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort |  awk '$0 > "./reference"'
```

if you need the first

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort |  awk '$0 > "./reference"{print;exit}'
```

Comment: Thanks! A variation on this for getting *all* the files *between* the given *variables* would be: `awk '$0 >= "'"${FROM}"'" && $0 <= "'"${TILL}"'"'`

Answer (score 3):

eg. `script-name "$HOME" "reference"` ... `find` doesn't always output the leading `./`, as in the case of `find bin`, or `find /tmp`. So if you only want the file base-names, this works.

**update:** Added *tolower()* to allow for a case insensitive comparison, which produces the **alphabetical** collation mentioned in the question...

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="$1"; ref="$2"
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" | awk -v"ref=$ref" 'tolower($0) < tolower(ref)'
```

Just pipe it to `sort` after `awk`, if you need it sorted.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I changed the last part of the awk script to be `$0 < ref` and that works, but since there are no spaces in the output of find the $2 field doesn't exist. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, I made a quick change to it at the last moment, and missed that field (it originally had two *\xFF* delimited fields)... Now, that I've had a bit of sleep, I can see that it is not handling **case** properly. I assume that as the question refers to an *alphabetical* collation, it means *case insensitive*.  I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed` it is more concise:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | sed '/^\.\/reference/,$d'
```

Which means (after sorting) delete the reference line (or greater) and all lines following to the last line.

The sed 'd' command is used here with an address range, where '/^./reference/' is the start and '$' is the end of the range. (And '$' as an address means the last line.)

Answer (score 3):

Obligatory zsh answer, using the `.` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to select only regular files and `e` to further select among matches:

```
echo *(.e\''[[ $REPLY > reference ]]'\')
```